# Convert Plotly y axis from numeric to string

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

How can I format the y axis in Plotly as string instead of numeric?

I tried to convert the numeric into string with:

```
df.id= df.id.astype('str')
fig = px.scatter(x = df.Datetime, y = df.id, color =df.Category
                                      )

fig.show()
```

but the plot displayed the numeric in million, as below:

[image]

How can I get the y axis showing the complete digits as string?

Comment: Please refer to the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#enumerated-ticks-with-tickvals-and-ticktext) for examples of making arbitrary strings. It can be used as a set of value and string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fig.update_yaxes(tickformat='d')` might be used to change the formatting [rules](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/tree/v1.4.5#d3-format) to show decimal numbers

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @bartolo-otrit's solution:

```
fig.update_yaxes(type='category', title = 'Title')
```

also worked by converting data type to categorical.